# I've let Arvel the Swift ran away, can I still find him?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've let Arvel the Swift ran away after freeing him.

> I didn't know he had the golden claw in his possesion.

So, now I can't complete that quest anymore... Where can I find him?

Comment: After not finding Arvel after he ran away, but arriving at the puzzle door that requires the golden claw, I had to backtrack to the first room with Draugr. While in that room Arvel ran up to me and attacked. I killed him and got the claw... but still wonder where he'd been hiding!

Comment: That's wierd I Followed him through a few rooms and he just turned around and attacked me, and he's not very fast for someone named 'Arvel the Swift'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keep moving along the path. You'll find he's met an unexpected fate at the hands of the denizens deeper within the barrow, allowing you to retrieve the claw again.

Comment: Looks like they've hid him in a corner where I wouldn't look immediately, finally found him.

Comment: Help, I still can't find him! What room is he in, please?

Comment: @Hellp: You are going to have to check all bodies on the entire floor of the dungeon, it took me some time to notice that he got killed in a corner. He doesn't die on the same place, by the way...

Comment: @hellp He seems to always die in the next room, either to a Draegr, to the door trap, or somehow in the corner on the left-hand side as you enter the room

Comment: Getting piled into the corner appears to be the result of getting caught by the edge of the trap.  It can impart quite a lot of force!

Comment: I killed Arvel because he tried to run away from me, however, i kept going and didn't search his body... just to only realised that he obtains the golden claws, i went back to the room that he was slained by me but now I can't find his body... wat do i do? T_T

Answer (score 2):

For me, the game glitched.

I chased Arvel, followed him into the room with the draugr, watched him die, killed off the draugr, and his body was missing. I checked all around, only to find his body back in the spider web I cut him down from.